# Multi-part form data upload with Akka HTTP

Tags: akka, akka-http

I'm trying to figure out how to create a multi-part form data request
with Akka HTTP (client API) but I can't find a way to express form data.

Does anyone know how to create form data that would take a file or input stream?

Answer (score 0):

I guess a bit late right now, but this [example](https://gist.github.com/jrudolph/08d0d28e1eddcd64dbd0), has both a client and a server.

I copy the relevant part

```
  def createEntity(file: File): Future[RequestEntity] = {
    require(file.exists())
    val formData =
      Multipart.FormData(
        Source.single(
          Multipart.FormData.BodyPart(
            "test",
            HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/octet-stream`, file.length(), SynchronousFileSource(file, chunkSize = 100000)), // the chunk size here is currently critical for performance
            Map("filename" -> file.getName))))
    Marshal(formData).to[RequestEntity]
  }

  def createRequest(target: Uri, file: File): Future[HttpRequest] =
    for {
      e ← createEntity(file)
    } yield HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, uri = target, entity = e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to achieve this would be:

```
val formData = Multipart.FormData.
                         fromFile("<FORM_DATA_KEY>", 
                                   MediaTypes.`application/octet-stream`, 
                                   file = file, 
                                   100000)

val httpRequest = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.POST, uri = target, entity = formData.toEntity)
```

On the first line you can also use `Multipart.FormData.fromPath` which will accept file path instead of file object itself.