# How to build a multipart form http request with Akka in Java?

Tags: java, scala, http, akka, multipartform-data

I can create simple http requests with Akka in Java:

```
// PUT request
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.PUT(uri).withEntity(someString).addHeader(HttpHeader.parse("Authorization", token));
// GET request
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.create(uri).addHeader(HttpHeader.parse("Authorization", token));
```

But how do I create a `multipart/form-data` POST request?  Specifically, I need to send one file and three text values in the form.

The [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30632311/multi-part-form-data-upload-with-akka-http) of [doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046266/how-to-represent-a-form-data-request-using-akka-http) that I can find are all in Scala, and I don't know how to translate that into the Akka Java API.  Does anyone know where I can find a working example in Java?

```
// POST request
HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.POST(uri).withEntity(???).addHeader(HttpHeader.parse("Authorization", token));
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured this out.  There is a helper class called `Multiparts` that has methods that can be used to create the entity:

```
RequestEntity entity = Multiparts.createFormDataFromParts(
    Multiparts.createFormDataBodyPartStrict("file", HttpEntities.create(ContentTypes.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "fileContent".getBytes())),
    Multiparts.createFormDataBodyPartStrict("key1", HttpEntities.create("value1")),
    Multiparts.createFormDataBodyPartStrict("key2", HttpEntities.create("value2")),
    Multiparts.createFormDataBodyPartStrict("key3", HttpEntities.create("value3"))
).toEntity();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.POST(uri).withEntity(entity).addHeader(HttpHeader.parse("Authorization", token));
```

There may well be a better way, but this seems to be working so far.